# Get all combinations of elements of multidimensional array in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, nested-loops

Imagine a matrix with 3 rows and 3 columns containing the following elements:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]   
[1,]    1    4    7   
[2,]    2    5    8
[3,]    3    6    9
```

I would like to write a function that extracts every combination of triples with the first element from column1, the second element from column 2 etc. The first such triple might be

```
1,4,7, then
1,4,8
1,4,9
1,5,7
1,5,8 and so on
```

Each triple should be an argument to another function. In this example, there are 27 such triples, rows ^ columns in general.

While for this example, I could write 3 nested for loops iterating over the three columns, I would like to have a function that can handle any matrix with n rows and m columns.

In R, there is the `expand.grid` function available for this but I would like to have a plain C++ solution (without calling Rcpp).

If I have:

```
std::vector<double> col1 = {1,2,3};         
std::vector<double> col2 = {4,5,6};
std::vector<double> col3 = {7,8,9};
std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix = {col1,col2,col3};

std::vector<std::vector<double>> result = generateGrid(matrix);
// result should contain [[1,4,7], [1,4,8], etc];
```

Comment: There's something fundamental that appears to be missing from your question. That would be an actual question. What exactly are you asking? All you've written here is a vague description of some function you're trying to write. Ok, well, make it so, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got it right, your problem is same as printing all n-tuples, where each element is in [0,m), which then will be indices to your m,n matrix .This can easily be done with recursion:

To print all n-tuples with elements from range [0,m):

```
for each number from [0,m):
 1. print number
 2. print all (n-1)-tuples with elements from range [0,m)
```

Which can be translated into following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using row_t = std::vector<double>;
using matrix_t = std::vector<row_t>;


void function_impl(size_t col, size_t row, const size_t numCols, const size_t numRows, row_t& rBuff, const matrix_t& m, matrix_t& result)
{
    rBuff[col] = m[row][col];

    if (col == numCols - 1)//If we've filled the permutation, append it to result
        result.push_back(rBuff);
    else//Fill rest of row with all possible combinations
    {
        for (size_t r = 0; r < numRows; ++r)
            function_impl(col + 1, r, numCols, numRows, rBuff, m, result);
    }
}

matrix_t function(const matrix_t& m)
{
    size_t numRows = m[0].size();//Assumes rectangular matrix
    size_t numCols = m.size();

    matrix_t result;
    row_t rowBuffer(numCols);//Buffer to store current permutation of indices

    //Places all possible indices into first element of permutation and recurses
    for (size_t r = 0; r < numRows; ++r)
        function_impl(0, r, numCols, numRows, rowBuffer, m, result);
    return result;
}



int main()
{
    row_t col1 = {1,2,3};
    row_t col2 = {4,5,6};
    row_t col3 = {7,8,9};
    matrix_t matrix = {col1,col2,col3};

    //Prints all 27 combinations
    for (const auto& row : function(matrix))
    {
        for (const auto& el : row)
            std::cout << el << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

It does use recursion to depth of number of columns with constant one-row memory. Of course, resulting matrix will contain m^n elements, but if you just need to print them, you can do that immediately instead of appending to result and get rid of result matrix all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
    
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    using namespace std;

    using matrix_t = vector < vector < double > >

    //class for simulating multiple for(int i=from ;i<=to;++i) in a row
    class multi_iterator
    {
    using Iterators = size_t*;


    private:
        Iterators iterators;   //array of iterators for multiple synchronized but different iterations
                               //through the same interval from-to

        size_t iter_amount;       //number of iterators in array above

        //all are iterating from - to
        size_t from;
        size_t to;



    public:
        multi_iterator(size_t number_of_iterators , size_t _from , size_t _to)
        {
            iter_amount = number_of_iterators;
            iterators = new size_t[number_of_iterators]();
            from = _from;
            to = _to;
        }


        int get_value(size_t iterator_id)// iter_id is the index of an iterator inside array iterators
        {
            return iterators[iterator_id];
        }


        int end()//if the last iterator is greater than "to" the iterations are over and the function returns true
        {
            if( iterators[iter_amount-1] >to )
                return true;

            else return false;
        }


        //increments in a synchronized order
        void operator++()
        {
            int iter_id = 0;

            while(iter_id < iter_amount)    //start the loop with the first iterator
            {
                if(iterators[iter_id] < to) //if the iterator didnt reach the upper boundary "to"
                {
                    ++iterators[iter_id];   //increment the iterator
                    break;
                }

                else if( iterators[iter_id] == to  )    //if the iterator reached the upper boundery "to"
                {
                    if( iter_id < iter_amount-1 )       //if it's not the last iterator
                    {
                        iterators[iter_id]=0;    //turn the iterator back to 0
                        ++iter_id;               //move on to the next iterator
                        continue;                //continue the loop with the next iterator
                    }

                    else                        //the last iterator reached the upper boundery
                    {

                        ++iterators[iter_id];   // the iterations are over
                        break;

                    }

                }


            }

        }


    };

    void function(const matrix_t& matrix)
    {
        size_t columns = matrix.size();

        if(columns > 0 )
        {
            size_t rows    = matrix[0].size();

            multi_iterator it(columns , 0 , rows-1 );//we need a row-iterator(from 0 to "row") for every column

            while( !it.end() )
            {
                for(size_t i=0;i < columns;++i)
                {
                    size_t iter_value_column_i = it.get_value(i);

                    cout<< matrix[i][ iter_value_column_i ]<<" ";
                }
                cout<<endl;
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        std::vector<double> col1 = {1,2};
        std::vector<double> col2 = {4,5};
        std::vector<double> col3 = {7,8};
        std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix = {col1,col2,col3};



        function(matrix);


        return 0;
    }
```